# The satellite assembly named "XX.dll" for fallback culture "en-US" could not be found error in .NET app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, satellite-assembly

I'm customizing an open-source .NET application.  It compiles perfectly fine. But forms and controls refuse to show in designer, throwing the following error:

> The satellite assembly named "XX.dll"
>   for fallback culture "en-US" either
>   could not be found or could not be
>   loaded. This is generally a setup
>   problem. Please consider reinstalling
>   or repairing the application.

I know it's a multilingual application, but I'd like to drop additional languages and stick to simple captions customization via form designer.

Also, the issue prevents from adding images to controls. The same exception occurs on lines as the following one:

```
((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("ItemXXX.Glyth")));
```

What do I need to change in order to disable satellite assembly resources?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.

Removing the following line from AssemblyInfo solved the problem:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

Answer (score 4):

That's a way to remove the issue, but to **fix** it, add a `UICulture` to your `PropertyGroup`s in the project file that matches the 
`NeutralResourcesLanguage` used in the `AssemblyInfo` file.  You can then satisfy FxCop warning CA1824 if you ever need to.
e.g. In `AssemblyInfo`:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-GB", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

In project file (e.g. .csproj):

```
    ...
    <PropertyGroup Condition="...">
        ...
        <UICulture>en-GB</UICulture>
        ...
    </PropertyGroup>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error only once, when trying to add a reference to a project.

I solved it simply restarting Visual Studio.